# Cookie limit on the site's individual pages

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, header, http-headers

So I know browsers limit the cookie number to something like 200 ...or whatever (the idea is that there is a limit).

<strike>I need to mark a site's page as *viewed* by the current visitor, so I'm setting a cookie `viewed=true`.</strike>

- How can I set a cookie only for a certain page? I know it's possible, I've seen sites doing this...
- Let's say I have 10.000 pages and a visitors views them all. Would browsers complain if there are like 10.000 cookies set on his computer for each of these pages? Is there a cookie limit for the entire site too (all pages together) ?

**better explanation of what I want:**

Cookies can be set as global (for the entire site, visible on all pages), or local (for a certain page only).

- How can I set a local cookie? For example a cookie that's only accessible from  `site.com/?page=blablawhatever`
- Does the cookie number browser limit take in consideration all local cookies too, or just the cookies for the current site page?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal way would be to set a user ID cookie and, like the others said, store any information tied to that user in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session cookie and store the viewed pages on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cookies (which is on the user's end).

When a user goes to one of your pages, save to the data base that he/she went there.

Before the database save check of the user was already there before, and if that is true then don't save it to the database.